# how to correctly implement a Button to hide R code in RMarkdown/html

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

I am doing some exercises for my students using RMarkdown and a piece of code I was using begore, from Ronak Bhatt, but it is not working corretly anymore. Instead R code in correct format, I am having ```r ... like a text output.

Below I am posting all setting to have a button that hide/unhide the code in html. I really appreciate any help.
Thanks!

In the R Markdown yaml I have:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "..."
date:  "`r Sys.Date()`" 
output: 
  html_document:
    includes:
      in_header: scripts/uncover.html 
...
---
```

In knitr setup I have:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
uncover <- function(before, options, envir) {
     if (before) {
         id <- options$id
         button_string <- paste0("<button onclick=\"uncover('", 
                                 id, 
                                 "')\">Solução</button>")
         div_string <- paste0("<div id = '", id, 
                              "', style = 'display:none'>")
         paste(button_string, div_string, sep= "\n")
     }
     else {
         "</div><br>"
     }
 }
````

And in script uncover.html I have:

```
<script>
function uncover(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
      x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630248/collapsing-hiding-figures-in-r-markdown). RMarkdown is friendly with HTML and will allow raw HTML in Rmarkdown as long as it's used properly. I didn't use your uncover.html file, because I used other HTML code directly inside Rmarkdown.

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "..."
date:  "`r Sys.Date()`" 
output: 
  html_document:
    includes:
      in_header: uncover.html
---
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#BlockName"> Show/Hide </button>  
<div id="BlockName" class="collapse">  


```{r}

uncover <- function(before, options, envir) {
     if (before) {
         id <- options$id
         button_string <- paste0("<button onclick=\"uncover('", 
                                 id, 
                                 "')\">Solução</button>")
         div_string <- paste0("<div id = '", id, 
                              "', style = 'display:none'>")
         paste(button_string, div_string, sep= "\n")
     }
     else {
         "</div><br>"
     }
 }

```

</div>
````

Comment: but now I am wondering how to have this work with multiple buttons?

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been quite some time, but as I stumbled upon the excellent answer from [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61492954) when I tried to solve the same problem, I wanted to contribute my adapted solution.

By adding the following code to a code chunk at the beginning of the R markdown document, a new code chunk option called `button` is added. If it is set, the code chunk is hidden behind a button with a name equal to the value of the `button` code chunk option.

```r
local({
  hook_chunk <- knitr::knit_hooks$get('chunk')
  knitr::knit_hooks$set(chunk = function(x, options) {
    if (!is.null(options$button)) {
      rnd_id <- substr(tempfile("b", "", ""), 2, 9)
      paste0(
        '<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#',
        rnd_id, '">',
        options$button, '</button> <div id="',
        rnd_id, '" class="collapse">',
        x, '</div>')
    } else {
      x
    }
  })
})
```

`NAME` is the name of the button and `ID` needs to be a unique identifier. The function therefor  generates a random ID for every individual code chunk. I know that this is by no means a good solution… but it works.

The function is a modification of a function in the R Markdown Cookbook section 12.1 [Redact Source Code](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/hook-hide.html). To achieve the desired effect, the knitr chunk hook is redefined to paste the necessary raw HTML code above and below the actual code chunk if the `button` option is set.