# R markdown: datable within collapsible section

Tags: r, r-markdown

Below is a R-markdown document with `<details>` tags to create collapsible sections.
Can you help me to render the `datatable` from section 2 in the html output?

**Minimal reproducible example**

````
### Section 1
<details> <summary>Click to expand</summary>
  
```{r, echo=FALSE}
head(iris)
```

</details>


### Section 2
<details> <summary>Click to expand</summary>
  
```{r, echo=FALSE}
DT::datatable(iris)
```

</details>
````

[image]

Comment: reactable might be a better option, unless you have to stick with DT.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. `reactable` works really fine and provides a perfect alternative to `datatable`. I you make it an answer, I will accept.

Comment: Done. See below. The HTML widgets based  pkgs have some strange side effects when adding extra html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, `reactable` will work with similar output and configurations.

Within an Rmd document:

````
<details><summary>Click to expand</summary>

```{r}
library(reactable)
reactable(mtcars)
```

</details>
````

Which renders to:

[image: Reactable working]

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer, but slightly too long to be a comment, so I've included it here. Hopefuly someone can use it to work out an actual answer:

The good new is that it is definitely "possible". The bad news is "it is not easy". With my limited knowledge of web-dev the problem seems to be, that `DT::datatable` (or more correctly `htmlwidgets:::print.html_widget`) creates an entire html-webpage in a temporary file, and this is the default method for visualizing `DT::datatable`. The file itself looks something like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<style>body{background-color:white;}</style>
<script src="lib/htmlwidgets-1.5.3/htmlwidgets.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="lib/datatables-css-0.0.0/datatables-crosstalk.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="lib/datatables-binding-0.16/datatables.js"></script>
<link href="lib/dt-core-1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="lib/dt-core-1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.extra.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="lib/dt-core-1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="lib/crosstalk-1.1.0.1/css/crosstalk.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="lib/crosstalk-1.1.0.1/js/crosstalk.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="htmlwidget_container">
  <div id="htmlwidget-cd5f37d21433eb2088ae" style="width:960px;height:500px;" class="datatables html-widget"></div>
</div>
<script type="application/json" data-for="htmlwidget-cd5f37d21433eb2088ae">{"x":{"filter":"none","data":[["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60","61","62","63","64","65","66","67","68","69","70","71","72","73","74","75","76","77","78","79","80","81","82","83","84","85","86","87","88","89","90","91","92","93","94","95","96","97","98","99","100","101","102","103","104","105","106","107","108","109","110","111","112","113","114","115","116","117","118","119","120","121","122","123","124","125","126","127","128","129","130","131","132","133","134","135","136","137","138","139","140","141","142","143","144","145","146","147","148","149","150"],[5.1,4.9,4.7,4.6,5,5.4,4.6,5,4.4,4.9,5.4,4.8,4.8,4.3,5.8,5.7,5.4,5.1,5.7,5.1,5.4,5.1,4.6,5.1,4.8,5,5,5.2,5.2,4.7,4.8,5.4,5.2,5.5,4.9,5,5.5,4.9,4.4,5.1,5,4.5,4.4,5,5.1,4.8,5.1,4.6,5.3,5,7,6.4,6.9,5.5,6.5,5.7,6.3,4.9,6.6,5.2,5,5.9,6,6.1,5.6,6.7,5.6,5.8,6.2,5.6,5.9,6.1,6.3,6.1,6.4,6.6,6.8,6.7,6,5.7,5.5,5.5,5.8,6,5.4,6,6.7,6.3,5.6,5.5,5.5,6.1,5.8,5,5.6,5.7,5.7,6.2,5.1,5.7,6.3,5.8,7.1,6.3,6.5,7.6,4.9,7.3,6.7,7.2,6.5,6.4,6.8,5.7,5.8,6.4,6.5,7.7,7.7,6,6.9,5.6,7.7,6.3,6.7,7.2,6.2,6.1,6.4,7.2,7.4,7.9,6.4,6.3,6.1,7.7,6.3,6.4,6,6.9,6.7,6.9,5.8,6.8,6.7,6.7,6.3,6.5,6.2,5.9],[3.5,3,3.2,3.1,3.6,3.9,3.4,3.4,2.9,3.1,3.7,3.4,3,3,4,4.4,3.9,3.5,3.8,3.8,3.4,3.7,3.6,3.3,3.4,3,3.4,3.5,3.4,3.2,3.1,3.4,4.1,4.2,3.1,3.2,3.5,3.6,3,3.4,3.5,2.3,3.2,3.5,3.8,3,3.8,3.2,3.7,3.3,3.2,3.2,3.1,2.3,2.8,2.8,3.3,2.4,2.9,2.7,2,3,2.2,2.9,2.9,3.1,3,2.7,2.2,2.5,3.2,2.8,2.5,2.8,2.9,3,2.8,3,2.9,2.6,2.4,2.4,2.7,2.7,3,3.4,3.1,2.3,3,2.5,2.6,3,2.6,2.3,2.7,3,2.9,2.9,2.5,2.8,3.3,2.7,3,2.9,3,3,2.5,2.9,2.5,3.6,3.2,2.7,3,2.5,2.8,3.2,3,3.8,2.6,2.2,3.2,2.8,2.8,2.7,3.3,3.2,2.8,3,2.8,3,2.8,3.8,2.8,2.8,2.6,3,3.4,3.1,3,3.1,3.1,3.1,2.7,3.2,3.3,3,2.5,3,3.4,3],[1.4,1.4,1.3,1.5,1.4,1.7,1.4,1.5,1.4,1.5,1.5,1.6,1.4,1.1,1.2,1.5,1.3,1.4,1.7,1.5,1.7,1.5,1,1.7,1.9,1.6,1.6,1.5,1.4,1.6,1.6,1.5,1.5,1.4,1.5,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.3,1.5,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.6,1.9,1.4,1.6,1.4,1.5,1.4,4.7,4.5,4.9,4,4.6,4.5,4.7,3.3,4.6,3.9,3.5,4.2,4,4.7,3.6,4.4,4.5,4.1,4.5,3.9,4.8,4,4.9,4.7,4.3,4.4,4.8,5,4.5,3.5,3.8,3.7,3.9,5.1,4.5,4.5,4.7,4.4,4.1,4,4.4,4.6,4,3.3,4.2,4.2,4.2,4.3,3,4.1,6,5.1,5.9,5.6,5.8,6.6,4.5,6.3,5.8,6.1,5.1,5.3,5.5,5,5.1,5.3,5.5,6.7,6.9,5,5.7,4.9,6.7,4.9,5.7,6,4.8,4.9,5.6,5.8,6.1,6.4,5.6,5.1,5.6,6.1,5.6,5.5,4.8,5.4,5.6,5.1,5.1,5.9,5.7,5.2,5,5.2,5.4,5.1],[0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.2,0.6,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,1.4,1.5,1.5,1.3,1.5,1.3,1.6,1,1.3,1.4,1,1.5,1,1.4,1.3,1.4,1.5,1,1.5,1.1,1.8,1.3,1.5,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.4,1.7,1.5,1,1.1,1,1.2,1.6,1.5,1.6,1.5,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.2,1.4,1.2,1,1.3,1.2,1.3,1.3,1.1,1.3,2.5,1.9,2.1,1.8,2.2,2.1,1.7,1.8,1.8,2.5,2,1.9,2.1,2,2.4,2.3,1.8,2.2,2.3,1.5,2.3,2,2,1.8,2.1,1.8,1.8,1.8,2.1,1.6,1.9,2,2.2,1.5,1.4,2.3,2.4,1.8,1.8,2.1,2.4,2.3,1.9,2.3,2.5,2.3,1.9,2,2.3,1.8],["setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","setosa","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","versicolor","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica","virginica"]],"container":"<table class=\"display\">\n  <thead>\n    <tr>\n      <th> <\/th>\n      <th>Sepal.Length<\/th>\n      <th>Sepal.Width<\/th>\n      <th>Petal.Length<\/th>\n      <th>Petal.Width<\/th>\n      <th>Species<\/th>\n    <\/tr>\n  <\/thead>\n<\/table>","options":{"columnDefs":[{"className":"dt-right","targets":[1,2,3,4]},{"orderable":false,"targets":0}],"order":[],"autoWidth":false,"orderClasses":false}},"evals":[],"jsHooks":[]}</script>
<script type="application/htmlwidget-sizing" data-for="htmlwidget-cd5f37d21433eb2088ae">{"viewer":{"width":450,"height":350,"padding":15,"fill":true},"browser":{"width":960,"height":500,"padding":40,"fill":false}}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

with data and header being obviously variable depending on the data.

Now if we inspect and edit the page while it is active by

1. In Rstudio call `DT::datatable(iris)` to show the table
2. Click the "show in new window" to open it in your preferred browser
3. Right-click anywhere on the page and click "Inspect element (Q)"
4. Right-click on "body" and click "Edit as HTML"
5. Finally add the `<details>` / `</details>` at the start and end of `<body>`

Then we can actually see that it works as we would expect (closed first):
[image: datatable-closed]

(open now):
[image: datatable-open]

So this is a clear conclusion that "it is possible". The problem is extracting the code. Walking down into `DT::datatable` you will eventually find that it calls `htmlwidgets:::print.html_widget` to open the actual html-page. This lets us recreate a script and extract the actual html code used in the widget:

```
#' Generate html and make dependencies available in directory for a DT::datatable
#' 
#' @param x a data.frame or DT::datatable
#' @param dir the (root) directory for the project/dependencies. See details
#' @param background background for the html widget
#' @param libdir directory to export dependencies to
#' 
#' @details This function generates the html that is usually generated when 
#' printing DT::datatable, and exports dependencies to a given directory, making
#' it useful for embedding the html into a markdown file or shiny script, either
#' running and saving this in the pre-amble/header or interactively. "Dir" 
#' can be used to specify the project root, with "libdir" specifying the path
#' relative from "dir" to place dependencies. Note that this likely enforces
#' the html file to be placed in the project root, and not a sub-folder of the 
#' project. 
datatable_html <- function(x, dir = getwd(), background = "white", libdir = 'lib'){
  if(is.data.frame(x))
    x <- DT::datatable(x)
  #from htmlwidgets:::print.html_widgets
  x <- htmltools::as.tags(x, standalone = TRUE)
  #from htmltools::save_html (called by print.html_widgets
  x <- htmltools::renderTags(x)
  deps <- lapply(x$dependencies, function(dep) {
    dep <- htmltools::copyDependencyToDir(dep, 
                                          libdir, 
                                          FALSE)
    dep <- htmltools::makeDependencyRelative(dep, dir, FALSE)
    dep
  })
  bodyBegin <- if (!isTRUE(grepl("<body\\b", x$html[1], 
                                 ignore.case = TRUE))) {
    "<body>"
  }
  bodyEnd <- if (!is.null(bodyBegin)) {
    "</body>"
  }
  c("<!DOCTYPE html>", "<html>", "<head>", 
    "<meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>", sprintf("<style>body{background-color:%s;}</style>", 
                                         htmltools::htmlEscape(background)), 
    htmltools::renderDependencies(deps, c("href", "file")), x$head, "</head>", 
    bodyBegin, # <=== body starts here, maybe remove?
    x$html, 
    bodyEnd, # <=== Body ends here, maybe remove?
    "</html>")
}

dt_html <- datatable_html(DT::datatable(iris))
# print (very large output):
cat(dt_html)
```

now `dt_html` contains the html segments in a vector, and the dependencies are copied to `{dir}/{libdir}` which should be a folder under the root of the markdown project. A few things to note: The html vector has the dependencies in `dt_html[6]` (may have to be included in the markdown pre-amble?) and the htmlscript itself is in `dt_html[10]` with body tags in `dt_html[9]` and `dt_html[11]` respectively.

I am not skilled enough with html embedding in Rmarkdown to be sure where to go from here, but I am certain that there will be some efficionados out there that has the proficiency to abuse this and providing the final part of the answer. I am assuming a combination of [document dependencies](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#document-dependencies) for the header and then using the html segment in `dt_html` somehow should do the job.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer (+1)

Comment: My pleasure. I hope it led to a solution. 

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

````
# Section 3
```{r}
library(shiny)
library(DT)  # make sure you load DT *after* shiny

    # Render
    renderDataTable({
      datatable(iris) %>% formatStyle(
        'Sepal.Width',
        backgroundColor = styleInterval(3.4, c('gray', 'yellow'))
      )
    })

```
````

It really bugged me that I couldn't figure it out, so I googled a bit and this should help you: https://blog.rstudio.com/2015/06/24/dt-an-r-interface-to-the-datatables-library/

The results is:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's indeed what I want, but with the use of 'datatable' instead of 'kable'. Is that possible?

Comment: Ah, I get the problem. I think the problem is that datatable itself creates an html that comes with a lot of extras. I can see the table I create under view-source:http://localhost:27697/session/viewhtml3878667414e5/index.html. In order to reproduce it you probably have to also add the .js scripts etc.

Comment: I've updated the answer. However my celebration was premature when you add <details></details>. It stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Using a button with the **div** tag instead of details works with DT :

````
### Section 1
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#BlockName1"> Show/Hide </button>  
<div id="BlockName1" class="collapse">  

```{r, echo=FALSE}
head(iris)
```

</div>


### Section 2
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#BlockName2"> Show/Hide </button>  
<div id="BlockName2" class="collapse">  

```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
DT::datatable(iris)
```

</div>
````

[image]

This based on this other answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46125161/14208185