# loading screen in shiny while calling a function from the server side

Tags: r, shiny

Hi I am writing a shiny app and on the server side code, I am calling a function when a user clicks the **Run** button. The issue I have is that the function takes around 10-25 minutes to run and a user might click the button multiple times during this period. After the function run is over, I show user the output path where the files have been downloaded and close the App. How can I prevent user from clicking the button multiple times, like a loading screen while the function is running?

```
observeEvent(input$runprocess, {
    rundownload()
    showModal(modalDialog(title ="Output folder: XYZ path",
                      actionButton("close", "Exit"),footer = NULL,
                      size = c("m"), easyClose = FALSE))
})

observeEvent(input$close, {
  js$closeWindow()
  stopApp()
})
```

Comment: By adding a modalDialog before you call `rundownload()`?

Comment: @JorisMeys How will the user then know that the download has finished?

Comment: because after the download has finished, you have a second modalDialog telling it has finished. I didn't say "remove the other one" ;-)

Comment: Now I realized I've seen that question before, so check the one I marked for some more variations on the same theme. But the general rule is you call any kind of code generating a loading message or whatever **before** you call the `rundownload()` in the same expression (i.e. the same `observe()` or `observeEvent()` call )

Answer (score 0):

By adding an extra modalDialog like this:

```
observeEvent(input$runprocess, {
    showModal(modalDialog(p("Start downloading. This might take a while"),
                         title = "download started",
              #etc etc
              ))
    rundownload()
    showModal(modalDialog(title ="Output folder: XYZ path",
                      actionButton("close", "Exit"),footer = NULL,
                      size = c("m"), easyClose = FALSE))
})

observeEvent(input$close, {
  js$closeWindow()
  stopApp()
})
```

And to prevent the user from clicking the Run button multiple times, you can use `shinyjs` to hide it after it has been clicked. See eg: [Hide shiny output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610555/hide-shiny-output)